# How can i fetch data from sqlite3 database using C++?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am new to c++ and how can i retrive data from sqlite3 db using SELECT query and callback method in my SqliteUtil class?

I know that the data can be collected using the callback method

**Method scheme readRecords() -> executeQuery() -> sqlite3_exec(callback)**

SqliteUtil.cpp

```
#include "SqliteUtil.hpp"

// for readRecords method
**static int SqliteUtil::callback(?char *record?, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    for(int i=0; i < argc; i++){
        cout <<     azColName[i];
        cout << "\t";
        cout << argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";**
    return 0;
}

// Thats execute query, just for DRY.
void SqliteUtil::executeQuery(string sql) {
    sql += ";";
    int result = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), callback, ?records_s?, &zErrMsg);
    printError(result);
}


void SqliteUtil::readRecords(vector<string> columns = {}, vector<string> order = {}) {
    string sql = "SELECT";
    if (columns.size() == 0 ) {
        sql += " * ";
    } else {
        sql += " " + joinStrArray(columns) + " ";
    }
    sql += "from " + table;

    if (order.size() != 0) {
        sql += " ORDER BY " + joinStrArray(order) + " ASC";
    }

    executeQuery(sql);
}
```

SqliteUtil.hpp

```
#ifndef SQLITE_UTIL_H
#define SQLITE_UTIL_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "../sqlite/sqlite3.h"
using namespace std;

class SqliteUtil
{
    private:
        string path; //path to database
        string table; //current table
        sqlite3 *db; //database reference
        char *zErrMsg;
        const char* data;
        //vector<vector<string>> records;
        char **records;

        string joinStrArray(vector<string> lines, int quoted=0);
        !!!!static int callback( ?char *records ?, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName);
        !!!!void executeQuery(string sql);
        void printError(int code);

    public:
        SqliteUtil(string dbPath, string tableName);
        //Setters and Getters
        void setPath(string dbPath);
        string getPath();
        void setTable(string tableName);
        string getTable();

        //Methods for work with Sqlite3
        void openDb();
        void closeDb();
        void createTable(vector<string> columns);
        void deleteTable();
        void createRecord(vector<string> values);
        !!!!void readRecords(vector<string> columns = {}, vector<string> order = {});
        string updateRecord();
        void deleteRecord(string id = "0");
};

#endif
```

Comment: Why are you using the callback interface in the first place?

Comment: Have you searched for examples on the internet?

Comment: Yeah, and i found some material, but dont understand